# Draw Inductive effect bond

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

[image: Inductive effect]

I want to draw Inductive effect on the bond of molecular. What is the code if I use [ChemFig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig?lang=en)?
Thank you.

Comment: The vast majority here doesn't have a background in chemistry. You should probably add a picture of the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

As I'm sure you know when you have used `chemfig` already the bonds have optional arguments. The manual says:

> **6 Customization of bonds**
>
> There is a fifth and last optional argument for bonds which is found
>   after the fourth comma:
>
> ```
> [,,,,<tikz code>]
> ```

This means all you have to do is adding the TikZ code for an arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\tikzset{ ind/.tip = {>[sep=5pt]_.} }

\begin{document}

\chemfig{H-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-[,,,,->]Cl}

\chemfig{H-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-[,,,,-ind]Cl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both of your two ways is perfect and in chemistry, they are all accepted. I prefer the latter but I not so good in tikz. I learn alot from your posts. Thank you.